# installing RCU for Configuring Oracle Identity And Mnagement

Tags: java, database, oracle, identity-management, rcu

I want to configure OIM < Oracle Identity and Access Management , so I followed the bellow instruction:

1. Installation of  fmw_12.2.1.3.0_infrastructure.jar
2. Installation of  fmw_12.2.1.3.0_soa_quickstart.jar
3. Installation of  fmw_12.2.1.3.0_idm.jar

Till now everything installed successfully, but the point is when I want to create a repository, RCU, after giving it the database details, I just see the "AS Common Shemas", actually I have to see the **SOA Suit** and **DM Schemas**, too, but I don’t see them to tick them. 
the [picture](http://atgwork.com/cloud/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/OIM_12c_9.png) shows the correct form. I can't see 2 below components.(SOA Suit and DM Schemas)

Why is the problem?
I have attached the link to clarify it more.
I would be grateful, if someone can help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer for those who need, I was working with MS SQL server, when I changed my DB to ORACLE, every thing was OK, and I saw the SOA suit and IDM components.